# Opera 10.7 window.location issues

Tags: javascript, opera

Does anyone know of any issues with using window.location in Opera 10.7. I don't seem to be able to change the hash, search, or even the href properties. It seems to completely ignore anything I tell it to do using window.location.

And before someone suggests it, no, upgrading to a newer version of Opera is not an option. And yes, I know 10.7 was not an officially released version of Opera, but it's not my choice to use it or not.

Comment: Can you give me code or instructions on how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry, unless you have access to an Enseo set top box, you won't be able to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this as whatever.xhtml and make sure you don't save it with a BOM (byte order mark), if you're not sure then save it using SuperEdi (freeware) and uncheck it in the save dialog.

This should be pretty self-explanatory, click on the object and it'll list all of it's child objects for you for whatever browser you use it with (I don't have a copy of Opera 10.7 as it never went beyond test release and they went straight to Opera 11.0).

Let me know if you need help with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Opera 10.7</title>
<script type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function dom_list(o)
{
 if (eval(o)==undefined) {alert('Error: that is not a valid object.');}
 else if (document.getElementById(o) && document.getElementById(o).childNodes.length>1)
 {
  change_toggle(o+'_children','overflow','hidden');
 }
 else
 {
  var dom_list = new Array();

  for (var a in eval(o)) {dom_list.push(a);}
  dom_list.sort();

  if (eval('typeof '+o+'.'+dom_list[i])=='function') {ao = o+'()';}
  else {ao = o;}
  var d1 = document.createElement('div');
  d1.setAttribute('id',ao+'_children');

  for (var i=0; i<dom_list.length; i++)//
  {
   if (eval('typeof '+o+'.'+dom_list[i])=='function')
   {
    ao = o+'.'+dom_list[i]+'()';
    var ab = ao.split('()')[0];
    ah = 'javascript:try{alert('+ao+'+\'/\n/\n\'+'+ab+');} catch(err) {alert('+ab+'(\'A test string.\'));}';
   }
   else
   {
    ao = o+'.'+dom_list[i];
    ah = 'javascript:dom_list(\''+ao+'\');';
   }

   var d2 = document.createElement('div');
   d2.setAttribute('id',ao);
   var a1 = document.createElement('a');

   a1.setAttribute('href',ah);
   var n2 = document.createTextNode(ao);
   a1.appendChild(n2);
   d2.appendChild(a1);
   d1.appendChild(d2);
  }

  document.getElementById(o).appendChild(d1);
 }
}

function change(id,newClass)
{
 if (document.getElementById(id)) {document.getElementById(id).className=newClass;}
 else if (id) {id.className=newClass;}
 else {alert('Error: the id \''+id+'\' was not found or has not yet been imported to the DOM.\n\nNew class intended: '+newClass);}
}

function change_toggle(id,c1,c2)
{
 if (document.getElementById(id))
 {
  if (document.getElementById(id).className==c2) {change(id,c1);}
  else {change(id,c2);}
 }
 else {alert('Error: the id \''+id+'\' was not found or has not yet been imported to the DOM.');}
}
//]]>
</script>
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
.hidden {display: none;}
a {font-size: 20px;}
a:hover {color: #000;}
div {margin: 4px;}
/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="window.location"><a href="javascript:dom_list('window.location');">window.location</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Due to the hardware the browser is running on, I can't alert or console log anything at any time.

Comment: Alrighty, can you at least open .xhtml files with Opera if you save them to the computer?

Comment: Updated the answer, use this to iterate over what is available to you.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Seems it doesn't know about those properties of window.location. Not good news, but at least now I know. Thanks again.